# Know when rotation is finished using setRequestedOrientation

Tags: android, rotation

I am trying to write an .apk to measure how long it takes to rotate the screen of an Android device (looping through a couple rotations).

I am using calls to `setRequestedOrientation()` to reoriente the screen in the 4 positions (`PORTRAIT`, `LANDSCAPE`, `REVERSE_PORTRAIT` and `REVERSE_LANDSCAPE`).

My problem is I am not able to tell when the rotation is finished. I have tried a few solutions, but each have their problems.

1. I tried to use `onConfigurationChanged()`. The problem is that this method gets triggered when the orientation change happens from the sensor, and not from `setRequestedOrientation()`. I actually have to call `setRequestedOrientation()` with the `FULL_SENSOR` parameter for `onConfigurationChanged` to work after my previous call to `setRequestedOrientation()`.
2. I have tried making `setRequestedOrientation()` sort of "blocking", by adding a while loop to check the screen orientation (in degrees). I called `android.view.Display.getRotation()` before `setRequestedOrientation()` and block with a while loop until it has changed. Unfortunately, it doesn't work either. It returns before the UI gets redisplayed.
3. I have tried to follow the life cycle of the activity, by waiting for `onCreate()` to get called again, to assume the rotation was done. Previously, I was looping until my counter reached a value, in each iteration calling `setRequestedOrientation()`. In this scenario, my while loop becomes an if statement, and I assume `onCreate` will call the function each time, but `onCreate()` doesn't get called after a couple of iterations. The UI doesn't seem to be redrawn as well.
4. A final solution that I have found online (but haven't fully been able to implement) is to use the `waitForIdleSync()` method right after `setRequestedOrientation()`. `waitForIdleSync()` is part of the Instrumentation class, and I think this is just made for testing and not for a standard .apk.

Any ideas would be really welcome. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html

You need to call enable() first, and then you get notified on EVERY rotation change your device is having.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to know when `setRequestedOrientation()` finished via Android API. The only way to know is to check the current orientation before calling it and after calling it in `onCreate()`.

In your `Activity` class do:

```
long timeStamp;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     if (savedInstanceState == null) {
          timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();     
     }
     else {
          timeStamp = savedInstanceState.getLong("state_time_stamp");
     }

     // For example, check how long it takes to switch from portrait to landscape. 
     // You can modify this part to check PORTRAIT, LANDSCAPE, REVERSE_PORTRAIT and REVERSE_LANDSCAPE.
     final int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;    
     if (orientation == Configuration.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
          return;
     }

     // We will reach here only after setRequestedOrientation() is done
     // and here's the time it took to change the orientation:
     final long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStamp; 
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
     outState.putLong("state_time_stamp", timeStamp);
}
```